# Terraform Azure Application Insights failing with 401 on random resources after Azure AD issues

Tags: terraform, azure-application-insights, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform library of different azure resources that were working fine the other day.  Since the Azure AD failure I can't run a `terraform plan` anymore without random application insight resources failing due to 401 Unauthorized

Tried re-running `az login` but unfortunately still receiving issues.

Every plan is resulting in a different application insight resource throwing a 401.

> Error: Error making Read request on AzureRM Application Insights
> '{resource-name}': insights.ComponentsClient#Get: Failure responding
> to request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
> returned an error. Status=401 Code="Unauthorized"
> Message="Unauthorized"
> InnerError={"diagnosticcontext":"1b8e2cf0-5fd5-4a0d-9b75-1093e63ecd18","time":"2020-09-29T16:32:34.3731943Z"}

Comment: Did you have any further luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried re-initializing your Terraform backend? Doing this sequence just resolved the issue for me.

`az login`
`terraform init`
`terraform plan`